# can I drop (sorting) variables in PROC REPORT?

Tags: sas

My code looks like this:

```
ods excel file="[URL]" options(sheet_interval='bygroup'
                    sheet_name="#byval(bladnamn)");
PROC REPORT data=export;
by bladnamn;
/* define variabelnamn / order order=internal;*/
define order / order order=internal;
define variabel / order order=internal;
run;

ods excel close;
```

And produces the following output:

[image]

I want a clean-looking report so ideally, I would like to drop the two lefternmost columns after using them for sorting. Can this be done? In that case how?

If this cannot be done, can I do the sorting in a previous step and have the order carry over to the output from PROC REPORT?

Comment: I think you mean NOPRINT.  DEFINE statement option.